# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mainloop'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from sys import platform as sys_pf
if sys_pf == 'darwin':
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import * 
import ui 

def init_UI():

    main = Tk()
    main.title('data2knowledge')
    n = Notebook(main)

    ProcessTab = Frame(n)
    MergeTab = Frame(n)
    LearningTab = Frame(n)
    ReportTab = Frame(n)
    AboutTab = Frame(n)

    n.add(ProcessTab, text = "Process")
    n.add(MergeTab, text = "Merge")
    n.add(LearningTab, text = "Learn")
    n.add(ReportTab, text = "Report")
    n.add(AboutTab, text = "About")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''initialize GUI and start it'''
    gui = init_UI()
    gui.mainloop()
```

The error I get when running this code is:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mainloop'

I believe I need this last if-statement / mainloop() function to get the interface up and running, but I keep getting this error. I really hope someone knows how to solve this! Thanks!

Comment: `init_UI` implicitly returns `None` and you give it the name `gui`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `init_UI` has no return. Therefore, with `gui = init_UI()`, gui is `None`.

Perhaps you meant to `return main` at the end of `init_UI`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `main` from `init_UI()`.
So add at the end of your function:

```
def init_UI():
   # ...
   return main
```

**Explanation**

Your `init_UI` function does not have any `return` statement. Thus doesn't return any value, which in Python is marked as `None`.

And thus the last two lines of your program effectively become:

```
 gui = init_UI()
 None.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

`init_UI()` returns `None` by default; this `None` value is assigned to gui.

```
gui = init_UI()
gui.mainloop()
```

You must return the `Tk` object `main` from init_ui, so it is assigned to `gui`, then call `mainloop` on ``gui`.